# Convert specific word to uppercase

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a document which have a specific words started with underscore ("_"). 
I need a regular expression for notepad++ to change it to uppercase.

I've tried this one but it doesn't work:

```
_\w+
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Search for:

```
(_\w+)
```

Replace by:

```
\U$1
```

... and you're done! (Make sure to click the "Regular expression" radio button in the lower left corner.)

My test was as follows.

Before:

```
Hi, this is a test _with some _words starting _WITH _Underscores
Let's try to _toUpper them all!
```

After:

```
Hi, this is a test _WITH some _WORDS starting _WITH _UNDERSCORES
Let's try to _TOUPPER them all!
```

Good luck!

Comment: `\L` converts to lowercase, `\E` ends conversion. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039226/regex-to-change-to-sentence-case/16830360#16830360).